# Arrange numbers from 1 to 9 such that between every pair of consecutive numbers there must be an odd amount of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

The problem consists of a sequence using numbers from 1 to 9, however, between 1 & 2 there must be an odd amount of terms, and the same for 2 & 3, 3 & 4, 4 & 5, and so on. For instance, the sequence $(9, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8)$ does not satisfy the conditions since between $7$ and $6$ there are 2 terms, and this also happens for $3$ and $2$.
I get the feeling that it is impossible to find such sequence, but I can't find a way to prove it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $1$ is in an even position in the sequence. What does that tell you about $2$?

Comment: I see, if $1$ is in an even position then $2$ must be too, and consequently $3$ as well. Does that mean that every number must be in an even position? Hence the impossibility (since there are only 4 even positions). Or am I confusing something?

Comment: @NotAMathematician Yes, that's exactly right. Logically, the positions of all the numbers must have the same parity, i.e., they're all even or all odd, which is impossible. There's nothing special about having $9$ numbers here; the same logic applies to any number except the trivial case $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set of numbers in odd positions and those in even positions.

If for some pair of consecutive numbers, one is in an odd position and the other in an even position, the condition fails (since there is an even number of terms between them)

Since there are $5$ numbers in odd position and $4$ in even position, there can be at most $4$ pairs of consecutive numbers in the odd set and $3$ in the even set.

However $1$ to $9$ contains $8$ pairs of consecutive numbers, showing that at least one pair cannot be contained in the sets themselves.